# How to call function to enter multiple integers into an array?

Tags: c#

So the code for the function (Named InsertMark) is below. How would you call this function to enter the marks for say 10 people into an array called iMarks?

```
static void InsertMark(int [] piMarkArray, int piStuNum)
{
  int iMark;

  Console.Write("Enter mark for student " + piStuNum + ": ");
  iMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  while (iMark < 0 || iMark > 100)
  {
    Console.Write("Not a percentage. Enter again: ");
    iMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  }

  //update array element with this mark
  piMarkArray[piStuNum] = iMark;
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: A for(int = 0; i < numStu; ++1) loop?

Comment: It's better for you to read a C# book. Is this homework or something?

Comment: Yeah. Basically people were having trouble with functions and this is the example question they gave. I was having trouble understanding it to be honest (Not too good at arrays/functions so far)

Comment: @user1762928 - This is a very poor example of C# style, and I wouldn't suggest trying to learn anything from it.

Comment: @bobson This is the style they are trying to teach. It's interesting to see that the examples are poor. It's probably why people are getting confused.

Comment: Hmm, this is the same quality as using recursion on big factorials.

Comment: @user1762928 - It's a very C++ way of coding, just using C# I/O instead.  I'll post an answer with more idiomatic C#, just so you know what it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the line `piMarkArray[piStuNum] = iMark;` inside while loop, use index, and exit the loop if index is not less than array length.

```
 int index=0;
 while ((iMark < 0 || iMark > 100) && index < piMarkArray.Length) // exit the loop array is full
 {
    Console.Write("Not a percentage. Enter again: ");
    iMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    piMarkArray[index++] = iMark; // Here marks are set
  }

  //update array element with this mark
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you create array which will hold `10` marks and fill it with your method in a loop:

```
int[] marks = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < marks.Length; i++)
    InsertMark(marks, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

In main function you could have a code:

```
 int iMarks[10];

for(int i = 0; i <10; i++ )
   InsertMark(iMarks, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    InsertMark(iMarks, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an array of size 10: `int[] iMarks = new int[10]`, then in a for loop pass the array and the counter value through to the function.

```
        int[] iMarks = new int[10];
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            InsertMark(iMarks, x);
```

Here is the full class/ working example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] iMarks = new int[10];
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            InsertMark(iMarks, x);

        Console.Read();

    }

    static void InsertMark(int[] piMarkArray, int piStuNum)
    {
        int iMark;

        Console.Write("Enter mark for student " + piStuNum + ": ");
        iMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while(iMark < 0 || iMark > 100)
        {
            Console.Write("Not a percentage. Enter again: ");
            iMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //update array element with this mark
        piMarkArray[piStuNum] = iMark;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are always multiple ways to code anything, and this is no exception.  What I'm putting here is **one example** of idiomatic C# to do this.   There are at least two variants I can think of which would be better, but this keeps the closest to the original idea.

First, a basic `Student` class:

```
class Student
{
   public int ID;
   public int Mark;
}
```

Then, a function to prompt for the mark

```
int GetMark(int studentID)
{
    Console.Write("Enter mark for student " + studentID + ": ");
    int mark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while (iMark < 0 || iMark > 100)
    {
        Console.Write("Not a percentage. Enter again: ");
        iMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    return mark;
}
```

Finally, from your main program, you have a list or array of `Student` objects called `AllStudents` and you do:

```
foreach (Student student in AllStudents)
{
    student.Mark = GetMark(student.ID); 
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you aren't using classes, your loop could be:

```
int[] marks = new int[10]; // Or whatever size it needs to be.
for (int i = 0; i < marks.Length; i++)
{
   marks[i] = GetMark(i);
}
```